# How to insert title for Rows of Cross Tab in Birt Tool

Tags: birt

i am very new to Birt Tool,

my Question is,

I Did Row spaning in Cross tab by using different rows, now i want to insert heading for each row,

Could anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

The reason this never got an answer is that Eclipse has not yet provided this long-awaited and much requested feature: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=261995

Several work-arounds though.  If you've found something that works well, let us all know.

Comment: The bug report linked in my answer seems to indicate this was finally added in January 2014.

Answer (score 1):

one workaround which i use is add a grid on top of the rows with same number of columns as in the crosstab and 1 row .

Now you can add labels in the grid for static headers

If you want dynamic headers you can choose the data from the pellete